# Why are some Typescript module names given as strings?

Tags: typescript, syntax, module, typescript-typings

Typically, Typescript modules are declared like

```
declare module MyModule {
     ....
}
```

but sometimes I also see it like

```
declare module "MyModule" {
     ....
}
```

I am wondering what is the purpose of giving the name as a string?

I checked in the [Typescript docs and found](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html)

> This is a common pattern for modules whose imported entities are callable functions

I tried compiling both `MyModule` and `"MyModule"` and they compile to the same thing. Does this mean that with or without quotes are equivalent, and deciding to use them is just like using capital letters for class names, or starting interface names with `I` etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As outlined in the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html), there is a difference between the two styles. `module x {` is equivalent to `namespace x {`, while `module "x" {` is unlike either of the other two. This is definitely confusing, which is why the documentation using the latter syntax in all cases.

The question then must be asked, what is the difference between a namepsace and a so-called external module (i.e., a module that is declared with quotes)?

We get some insight from the docs:

> Just like namespaces, modules can contain both code and declarations. The main difference is that modules declare their dependencies.
>
> Modules also have a dependency on a module loader (such as CommonJs/Require.js).

Essentially, using the quotes indicates that it is indeed a module in the traditional Javascript sense that requires explicit import to be used. Without the quotes, you just create a global object that can be referenced and utilized without any explicit `require`s.

Comment: `The main difference is that modules declare their dependencies`... how does a module declare its dependencies in Typescript? I haven't been able to find the syntax in the typescript docs

Comment: Via the import statement: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html. Think of it this way - `namespace`s cannot include (i.e., import) external modules, but are instead entirely meant for truly internal structuring of  code. I think this is why external modules are basically always recommended, as they can scale to larger projects, where you typically want to separate common code out to external modules.